# unable to subscribe multiple observable using withlatestfrom

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have three observables and need pass those values to service as a param so i'm trying to acheive this using **WithLatestFrom()** but its working fine when i have all values as a observable.

```
this.payment$.pipe(
withLatestFrom(this.first$, this.second$, this.three$)
).subscribe((v, first, second, three) => {
this.methodInfoService.fetchInfo(v, first, second, three)
})
```

But the problem is, the first observable sometimes might be undefined so that time i'm unable to subscribe other two observales. Please suggest if any alternative solution to acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use combineLatest/withLatestFrom, you have to ensure all observables emit at least one value. So in this case the solution depends on your expectation. You can set default value for first$. For example

```
withLatestFrom(this.first$.pipe(startWith('yourDefaultValue')), this.second$, this.three$)
```